# shippingAddress.postcode set value

Tags: magento2, checkout

I need to set postcode value 
[image]

I have read about using a plugin:

```
<type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
        <plugin name="set_postcode" type="Vendor\ModuleName\Plugin\Model\Checkout\LayoutProcessorPlugin" sortOrder="10"/>
    </type>
```

**LayoutProcessorPlugin.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Plugin\Model\Checkout;
class LayoutProcessorPlugin
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject
     * @param array $jsLayout
     * @return array
     */

    public function afterProcess(
        \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
        array  $jsLayout
    ) {

        $codPostal = $this->_dataHelper->getCodPostal();


        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']
        ['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']
        ['children']['postcode']['value'] = $codPostal;
```

This works fine if ShippingAddress is not in cache.

How can I disable the cache of the postcode field's sending information, so that the value is always refreshed?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to fill value at the postcode, why don't you use a javascript instead? This way you do not need to worry about cache.

Comment: Can you tell me an example, please?